# Like AM-GM (Inequality with six variables)

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positive numbers. Prove that:
$$\frac{x^2+a}{yz+b}+\frac{y^2+b}{xz+c}+\frac{z^2+c}{xy+a}\geq3$$
I tried AM-GM, C-S, a full expanding, but without success.

Thank you!

Comment: Tried Muirhead?

Comment: @Swapnil Das It's not symmetric

Comment: Hmm, I see. Sorry, I'm not good at inequalities haha.

Comment: Where is this problem?

Comment: @Word Shallow What do you mean?

Comment: It means this inequality can be found where ? This is source question ><"

Comment: @Word Shallow  This inequality is an old unsolved problem from AOPS. What do you think about my solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349388/

Comment: Dear Michael can you prove the case where c=0 ?

Comment: @FatsWallers I have a proof for $b=c=0$, :)

Comment: If you prove the case where $c=0$ you can apply the theorem (proposition 3) of this [link](http://gil.ro/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1/) leaf 67 or 323 if you begin leaf 257.Of course you have to make this substitution : $nb+pc=x^2$;$nc+pa=y^2$;$na+pb=z^2$ and $\alpha a +Yc=yz$;$\alpha b +Ya=xz$;$\alpha c +Yb=xy$ . If you sum all of these equalities you have and divide you get this condition without $a,b,c$ : $$\frac{p+n}{\alpha+Y}=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{xy+yz+zx}$$.And I forgot $m=1$ and $\beta=1$.

Answer (score 0):

With computer, here is a solution:

Applying C-S, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{(x^2+a + y^2 + b + z^2+c)^2}{(yz+b)(x^2+a) + (zx+c)(y^2+b) + (xy+a)(z^2+c)} \ge 3$$
or 
$$(x^2+a + y^2 + b + z^2+c)^2 - 3(yz+b)(x^2+a) -3 (zx+c)(y^2+b) -3 (xy+a)(z^2+c) \ge 0.$$

Let $x = x_1,\ y = x_2, \ z = x_3, \ a = x_4^2, \ b = x_5^2,\ c = x_6^2$. It suffices to prove that
\begin{align}
&   x_1  ^4 + 2\,    x_1  ^2\,    x_2  ^2 - 3\,    x_1  ^2\,   x_2 \,   x_3  + 2\,    x_1  ^2\,    x_3  ^2 + 2\,    x_1  ^2\,    x_4  ^2 -    x_1  ^2\,    x_5  ^2 + 2\,    x_1  ^2\, x_6  ^2 - 3\,   x_1 \,    x_2  ^2\,   x_3  - 3\,   x_1 \,   x_2 \,    x_3  ^2\\
 &- 3\,   x_1 \,   x_2 \,    x_6  ^2 - 3\,   x_1 \,   x_3 \,    x_5  ^2 +    x_2  ^4 + 2\,    x_2  ^2\,    x_3  ^2 + 2\,    x_2  ^2\,    x_4  ^2 + 2\,    x_2  ^2\,    x_5  ^2 -   x_2  ^2\,    x_6  ^2
 - 3\,   x_2 \,   x_3 \,    x_4  ^2 +    x_3  ^4 \\
 &-    x_3  ^2\,    x_4  ^2 + 2\,    x_3  ^2\,    x_5  ^2 + 2\,    x_3  ^2\,    x_6  ^2 +    x_4  ^4 -    x_4  ^2\,    x_5  ^2 -    x_4  ^2\,    x_6  ^2 +    x_5  ^4 -    x_5  ^2\, x_6  ^2 +    x_6  ^4
\ge 0
\end{align} 
for all real numbers $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6$.

It is true since we can express it as SOS (Sum of Squares): ($A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ are all positive semidefinite)
$$\frac{1}{14}\Big(z_1^TA_1z_1 + z_2^T A_2 z_2 + z_3^TA_3z_3 + z_4^TA_4z_4\Big)$$
where 
$$z_1 = \left(\begin{array}{c}    x_1  ^2\\    x_3  ^2\\    x_6  ^2\\    x_5  ^2\\    x_4  ^2\\   x_2 \,   x_3 \\    x_2  ^2\\   x_1 \,   x_2 \\   x_1 \,   x_3  \end{array}\right)
, z_2 = \left(\begin{array}{c}  {x_3}\,  {x_4}\\  {x_1}\,  {x_4}\\  {x_2}\,  {x_4} \end{array}\right), z_3 = \left(\begin{array}{c}  {x_3}\,  {x_5}\\  {x_1}\,  {x_5}\\ {x_2}\, {x_5} \end{array}\right), z_4 = \left(\begin{array}{c}  {x_3}\,  {x_6}\\  {x_1}\,  {x_6}\\  {x_2}\,  {x_6} \end{array}\right),$$
$$A_1 = \left(\begin{array}{ccccccccc} 14 & 2 & 2 & -10 & 8 & -18 & 2 & 0 & 0\\ 2 & 14 & 8 & 2 & -10 & 0 & 2 & -18 & 0\\ 2 & 8 & 14 & -7 & -7 & -3 & -10 & -12 & 15\\ -10 & 2 & -7 & 14 & -7 & 15 & 8 & -3 & -12\\ 8 & -10 & -7 & -7 & 14 & -12 & 2 & 15 & -3\\ -18 & 0 & -3 & 15 & -12 & 24 & 0 & -3 & -3\\ 2 & 2 & -10 & 8 & 2 & 0 & 14 & 0 & -18\\ 0 & -18 & -12 & -3 & 15 & -3 & 0 & 24 & -3\\ 0 & 0 & 15 & -12 & -3 & -3 & -18 & -3 & 24 \end{array}\right),
$$
$$A_2 = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 6 & 3 & -9\\ 3 & 12 & -15\\ -9 & -15 & 24 \end{array}\right),$$
$$A_3 = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 24 & -9 & -15\\ -9 & 6 & 3\\ -15 & 3 & 12 \end{array}\right),$$
$$A_4 = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 12 & -15 & 3\\ -15 & 24 & -9\\ 3 & -9 & 6 \end{array}\right).$$