# I have been trying this inequality for weeks and I just can't seem to solve it

Tags: inequality

If $a,b,c>0$ prove that $\frac{{(1+a)}^{2\ }{(1+b)}^2}{1+c^2}\ +\ \frac{{(1+b)}^2{(1+c)}^2}{1+a^2}\ +\frac{{(1+c)}^2{(1+a)}^2}{1+b^2}\ \geq\ 8(a+b+c)$
I have tried factorising, using the mean inequality, Schur's inequality, Cauchy's and even tried a trigonometric approach but nothing seems to work.

Comment: It would be great if you could show any of those tries so that people would not repeat that wasting their time (or address the mistake instead).

Answer (score 4):

Using the AM-GM inequality, we have
$$(1+a)^2(1+b)^2 = \left[(1+ab)+(a+b)\right]^2 \geqslant 4(a+b)(1+ab) = 4\left[b(1+a^2)+a(1+b^2)\right].$$
Therefore
$$\sum \frac{{(1+a)}^{2\ }{(1+b)}^2}{1+c^2} \geqslant 4 \sum \frac{b(1+a^2)+a(1+b^2)}{1+c^2}$$
$$ = 4 \sum a\left(\frac{1+b^2}{1+c^2}+\frac{1+c^2}{1+b^2}\right) \geqslant 8(a+b+c).$$

Comment: I appreciate your solution very much (+1), in economically using AGM twice
(thus should be +2).

Answer (score 0):

I put the right side on the left and typed the function into Maple and then had Maple find the gradient of the function and then find all the points where the gradient was $0$.  It gave $(1,1,1)$, $(-1,1,1)$, $(1,-1,1)$, $(1,1,-1)$, and some complex roots.

All of these values make the inequality true, and the minimum of the function must occur at one of these four points.  (The quadratic terms all have positive coefficients, so the min exists and lives inside some ball containing the origin.)